# Rails apply a method to all integers in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to multiply all integers with 1,25 that is called in view.

Is there a smart way to do this without having to create a helper method and apply it to all integers in view?

Example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id
    #pesudo code
    def integer
    this * 1.25
    end

end
```

It is best if it is possible to do it in the controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Product` model has a `value` attribute, for example, just write a class method and then you can call it wherever and for any object of that type.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  value_with_weight weight
    value*weight
  end
end
```

then use `@product.value_with_weight(1.25)` for example, wherever you want..

EDIT: What you're actually asking for sounds like you want to override the Integer class just in the scope of your particular model, which is a pretty horrible way to achieve that. However, sounds kinda like what [Refinements](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-refinements-an-overview-of-a-new-proposed-ruby-feature-3978.html) are meant to do in Ruby 2.0

Comment: Jeb Refinements are what I am looking for.